# Windows 10 randomly places new desktop icons in top left corner

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop, desktop-icons

Sometimes when I, for example, extract a folder from an archive with WinRAR to the desktop, the folder gets placed in the top left corner of the desktop and messes up the ordering of other icons. But when I move the folder to a proper position and move the other icons back to place and then extract another folder, it works normally. WinRAR is not the only program this happens with though. Seems like it can happen with any program that creates a folder or file on the desktop.

This happens randomly and I havent found any way to reproduce it reliably.
Dragging items to the desktop works normally still.

I have always had "Align icons to grid" enabled and "Auto arrange icons" disabled.
This problem started occuring only recently. I'm using Windows 10 Pro, build 18363.
I'm not 100% sure but I suspect that this started happening after installing Windows update KB4556799 or KB4552931 as those are most recent while others were installed a month ago.

[Illustration of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kML5x.gif)

Comment: A screenshot would help here.

Comment: @NiallUK I added an illustration about the problem.

Comment: `KB4556799 and KB4552931` were both released last week not a month ago.  If you suspect those updates you should temporarily uninstall them.  Your illustration does not clarify your problem, what I see in the illustration, is typical behavior.

Comment: Have you enabled sorting for the desktop icons (see context menu -> "sort by" on free space of the desktop).

Comment: @Ramhound I meant that the two updates are the most recent ones and other than those, nothing else before them had been installed in a month. Typical behaviour to what? It has never been like this on any Windows machine i have used. All files/folders created on the desktop have been added to an empty space without moving any existing icons.

Comment: @Robert No type of sorting has been enabled on the desktop and I haven't changed any other settings related to the desktop either.

Comment: Corrupt user profile?  Try creating a new user and logging on as them.  See if it happens under the new user profile.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I made a new account and the same behaviour occurs there. I then tested again on this account and the problem still occurs. If I delete the newly created folder and move all icons back in place and then re-create the new folder using the program, it then goes in the right place (which is the empty space after the existing icons)

Comment: have you deleted all desktop.ini files from your desktop?  Might help.. I doubt it.. but won't hurt.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I tried that at first but dint seem to have any effect that time. Now after a day of not using the desktop, it seems to work like expected.. https://superuser.com/questions/1058784/ was another similar case 4 years ago and it remains unsolved so I doubt there is any reliable solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got auto arrange icons selected on the desktop?  Try to right click the desktop and untick this and you should be free to arrange icons as you wish.  I think also if you open the desktop via the file explorer the problem won't happen.